# Splitting multiple elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, split

I've hit an issue I didn't think of. It's okay when I've got an array of data with only one of each element name say [name], [date], [id] because I just just put it into a variable for example $variable['name'] but I'm a bit lost when it comes to big arrays where say I've got 3 seasons worth of data (so season1, season2, season3) in one array so there is [name] 3 times, or [score] 3 times because there's 1 for each season..

Live example to help: http://vaughanslater.com/amphios

```
    <?php
        $summoner_name = 'amphios';
        $summoner_id = 21554735;

        $profile = new riotapi('euw');

        $summonername = $profile->getSummonerByName($summoner_name);
        $json = $summonername;

        // turns raw data into array
        $test = json_decode($json, true);

        // raw data
        //var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

        echo 
        'Summoner name: ' . $test['name'] . '<br />' .
        'Summoner ID: ' . $test['id'] . '<br />' .
        'Profile icon ID: ' . $test['profileIconId'] . '<br />' .
        'Summoner level: ' . $test['summonerLevel'] . '<br />';

        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';

        $summonerstats = $profile->getStats($summoner_id);
        $json2 = $summonerstats;

        print_r($summonerstats);

        // turn raw data into array
        $test2 = json_decode($json2, true);

        // raw data
        var_dump(json_decode($json2, true));

        echo $test2['totalChampionKills'][0];

        //$summonername = $profile->getSummonerByName($summoner_name);
        //print_r($summonername);

        //$summonerstats = $profile->getStats($summoner_id, 'ranked');
        //print_r($summonerstats);

        //$getsummoner = $profile->getSummoner($summoner_id, 'name');
        //print_r($getsummoner);

        //$getleague = $profile->getLeague($summoner_id);
        //print_r($getleague);
    ?>
```

So where the "echo" starts that's fine and works how I want, it turns the JSON data into a php array where I can place it into a variable. Now (further down) I want to Do the same but there's 3 sets of the same data (different results, same element names) in one array. How will I go about splitting this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop it up.. Make use of a `foreach` construct after you have decoded the JSON data.

```
foreach($test2 as $k=>$v)
{
echo "$k : $v";
}
```